# using facebook share link with sharepoint

Tags: facebook, sharepoint, share

I have added a facebook share link to my sharepoint site using:

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I have added the script to the masterpage and the link to the page layout. I all works fine apart from that when a new page is created using the masterpage with the script some of the editong tools are disabled. For example the Format and Markup Style Menus are disabled. Can this be problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/
It contains all the official Facebook plugins that you can embed into your site.  In your case you should look in specific at the [Send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/).

> The Send Button allows users to easily send content to their friends.
>   People will have the option to send your URL in a message to their
>   Facebook friends, to the group wall of one of their Facebook groups,
>   and as an email to any email address. While the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) allows
>   users to share content with all of their friends, the Send Button
>   allows them to send a private message to just a few friends.
>
> The message will include a link to the URL specified in the send
>   button, along with a title, image, and short description of the link.
>   You can specify what is shown for the title, image, and description by
>   using [Open Graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/).

It is very easy to implement these plugins - usually a case of "copy-and-paste".  It looks to me that you have been using an outdated method of the Facebook share feature.